# Django rest framework : POST on many to many

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following models :

```
class A(models.Model): 
 b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
 name = model.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
  name = model.CharField()
```

Urls in A app:

```
 url(
        r'^A/(?P<pk>[a-f0-9-]+)/B/$',
        AViewSet.as_view({
            'get': 'list',
            'post': 'create',
            'put': 'partial_update',
        }),
        name='A-B',
    ),
```

Serializer in A app :

```
class ABSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = A
        extra_kwargs = {
             'id': {'read_only': True},
        }
        fields = (
            'b',
        )
```

The issue is that when I call the POST call on the A app using the url :
`A/{idofA}/B` and send the post data of :

```
{
  b : ["idofexistingB"]
}
```

I get the error that the required field of A is not sent. This setup works for PUT call however.

The issue with PUT call is that when I call the PUT call again, it overrides the existing data in the AB relation field with the new data and not simply appends the data of second API call to the first.

How can I POST data so that I am able to link existing B records with A records?

Answer (score 7):

I once solved manytomany to fields in django with PrimaryKeyRelatedField. It assumes that the value for the fields comes as a list. I hope it will be helpful for you.

```
class ABSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = A
    fields = ('name', 'b')


 {'name': 'test', 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: Does this create the db table as the ManyToMany does?

Comment: Thank you Sijan Bhandari.  This was exactly what I needed all afternoon yesterday and this morning.   I kept trying serializers.ListField()... and 'RelatedModelSerializer'   .... and DynamicRelationField() .... and leaving the related model undefined in the Serializer.  None of them helped. PrimaryKeyRelatedField() solved my problem.  -sw

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, what do you mean by create db table? It will send the data as in the serializer format and will save without any interruption.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I'm having this problem right now, it's not saving the data in the many to many relation.

Comment: I thought I'd be spending a while on this issue but this really helped me! I was missing the 'read_only=True' in my serializer. Can you explain exactly what this does and why it is needed to create a post request with a m2m field?

Comment: @PixelsOfMind, when you have m2m field in your model and you want to save data using API, you either need to make sure you send all the relevant field for m2m object or you can just send m2m objects as list of primary keys [1,2] as above.  The serializer will maker sure to associate those integer values to corresponding instance in your table while saving them.